# Do alcohol-free mouthrinses have the same efficacy in terms of antiplaque and antigingivitis effect as mouthrinses that contain alcohol?

Tags: dentistry

The 2005 randomized control trial {1} concluded that:

> This randomized, controlled comparative clinical trial demonstrated that rinsing twice daily with the experimental alcohol-free 0.07% CPC rinse provides antiplaque and antigingivitis efficacy similar to that of the positive control EO rinse, a recognized antiplaque and antigingivitis mouthrinse that contains alcohol.

However, the authors have a conflict of interest since they work for Procter & Gamble, which owns Crest.

The 2018 randomized control trial {2} came to the same conclusion but also  has some competing interest (authors working for Johnson & Johnson Consumer Inc).

Have independent studies confirmed that alcohol-free mouthrinses have the same efficacy in terms of antiplaque and antigingivitis effect as mouthrinses that contain alcohol?

---

References:

- {1} Witt JJ, Walters PA, Bsoul SA, Gibb RO, Dunavent JO, Putt M. Comparative clinical trial of two antigingivitis mouthrinses. Am J Dent. 2005;18. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16178131
- {2} Lynch, Michael C., Sheila Cavalca Cortelli, James A. McGuire, Jane Zhang, Danette Ricci-Nittel, Carolyn J. Mordas, Davi Romeiro Aquino, and Jose Roberto Cortelli. "The effects of essential oil mouthrinses with or without alcohol on plaque and gingivitis: a randomized controlled clinical study." BMC oral health 18, no. 1 (2018): 6. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5763666/; https://doi.org/10.1186/s12903-017-0454-6

Comment: Great Q. I have wondered this myself, as I've heard this from dentist colleagues but haven't seen the evidence...